# Hardware necessary to Jenkins Ci with SonarQube

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube

I need your help and expertise to calculate the necessary hardware to an environment of code quality analysis by Jenkins maven and SonarQube. 
Currently we have 300 projects to build java is compiled using Maven 2.2.1, on average, each project contains fifty thousand lines of code.
I would to estimate the CPU, Ram and disc space required to perform this task for 1000 projects because they want to the future.
I searched for any article or an estimate of this information but have not found anything important, so I turn to their experience and knowledge.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Concerning Sonar, we provide a page with the [hardware requirements](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements#Requirements-HardwareRequirements), which actually gives some information about the web server and the database server.

For the "batch" part of Sonar (= the analyses that are launched by Jenkins), we do not give specific requirements. You would typically have several slaves that have several CPUs and a good amount of RAM, in order to be able to scale up when you have more and more Sonar analyses that need to be run more and more often. And those slaves (on which the analyses happen) should not be located to far from the DB on the network (otherwise performances will be affected by the network latency).

Comment: Thanks, great tips Fabrice!
I describe a bit the analyzed for Jenkins experts:
- Initial analysis suggests we have a server with jenkins (master) and n slaves, this n depends on something particular? Number of Jobs?
- It will have many executors as processors have both the master and the slave.
- The Sonar server would be dedicated, be nice to have more than one instance? few will be ideal, as many as executors or slaves?
On this basis we can relieve a little better hardware requirements necessary, any suggestions, or implementation experience will be highly valued by my!